# Overriding binary operators in derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, operator-keyword

Currently I am working on some algebra problem. I have an (almost abstract) base class from which several classes will be derived. All these classes will contain lists of numbers that are ordered in a lot of very different ways.
On the base class I want to define some operators that will be implemented for each of the derived classes. The idea is that once this library is finished, I don't have to care anymore about the intrinsics of the derived class. Once I initialize some derived class, I can refer to it by a reference (or pointer) of base-type and through that access all the derived operations.

I would like to setup rather complex algorithms, based on the operations that were defined on the base class. Therefore I want to be able to access these algorithms only via the base class. In that way it should easily generalize to many types of derived classes.
I have understood that this is exactly what object oriented programming is about, so that is why I ended up using C++.

I have setup most of what I want in a way similar to this example (works with g++):

```
#include <iostream>
class base;
base & gettype(const base&);
class base{
    public:
    int x;
    int type;
    base() = default;
    base(int in){
        this->type=0;
        this->x = in;
    }
    virtual base & operator+= ( const base & other){
        this->x += other.x;
        return *this;
    }
    virtual base & operator+ ( const base & other){
        base & ret = gettype(*this);
        ret += other.x;
        return ret;
    }
    virtual void print(){
        std::cout << "base is: " << x << "\n";
    }
};
class der1:public base{
    public:
    int a;
    der1(){}
    der1(int in){
        this->x = in;
        this->a = 2*in;
        this->type=1;

    }
    base & operator+= ( const base & other){
        std::cout <<"used der add\n";
        const der1 & otherder = static_cast<const der1 &>(other);
        this->x += otherder.x;
        this->a += otherder.a;
        return *this;
    }
    void print(){
        std::cout << "der1 is: " << x << " " << a << "\n";
    }
};
base & gettype(const base & in){
    if(in.type==0){
        return * new base();
    }
    if(in.type==1){
        return * new der1();
    }
}

main(){
    base baseobj(2);
    baseobj.print();
    baseobj += baseobj;
    baseobj.print();
    (baseobj+baseobj).print(); //Answer is right, but there is a memory leak

    der1 derobj(3);
    derobj.print();
    derobj += derobj;
    base * test = new der1(4);
    test->print();
    (*test) += (*test);
    test->print();
    base & test2 = *test;
    test2 += test2;
    test2.print(); //All these print the right answers as well
    delete test; 
}
```

But there is a memory leak inside this. Whenever I do something like `x=x+y`, then the memory that is allocated in the gettype function is not freed anymore.

I have read that it is rather uncommon to have an `operator+` function return a reference. However, I cannot make this work in a satisfactory manner when `operator+` returns by value. The reason is that when it returns by value, it will return an object sliced as `base` object. When I define derived `operator+` functions with covariant types (like in the example below), they are not used, because I only use `base` type references, not `der1`.

```
#include <iostream>
class base{
    public:
    int x;
    base() = default;
    base(int in){
        this->x = in;
    }
    virtual base & operator+= ( const base & other){
        this->x += other.x;
        return *this;
    }
    virtual base operator+ ( const base & other){
        base ret(*this);
        ret += other.x;
        return ret;
    }
    virtual void print(){
        std::cout << "base is: " << x << "\n";
    }
};
class der1:public base{
    public:
    int a;
    der1(int in){
        this->x = in;
        this->a = 2*in;
    }
    der1 & operator+= ( const der1 & other){
        this->x += other.x;
        this->a += other.a;
        return *this;
    }
    der1 operator+ ( const der1 & other){
        der1 ret(*this);
        ret += other.x;
        return ret;
    }
    void print(){
        std::cout << "der1 is: " << x << " " << a << "\n";
    }
};

main(){
    base baseobj(2);
    baseobj.print();
    baseobj += baseobj;
    baseobj.print();
    (baseobj+baseobj).print();  //This all works nicely for the base class

    der1 derobj(3);
    derobj.print();
    base * test = new der1(4);
    test->print(); //derived print function
    base & test2 = *test;
    test2 += test2; //base add function, because argument base&
    test2.print(); //Indeed, wrong answer.

}
```

So is it possible to create a library that I can use in a manner similar to this:

```
base & x = getderived(3) // This will return a (reference/pointer to) derived type
base & y = getderived(3)
x +=y;
x = x+3*y;
//And a whole lot of other operations

delete x
delete y // I don't mine some manual memory management
```

I hope it is clear what I want to achieve. If you think it is impossible, I'm also happy to with that answer, then I know I have to stop looking further. (If there's no solution, I'll keep my current approach and have to work with `+=` like operators, and skip the binary ones. This is not entirely bad)

Comment: You aren't overriding your virtual operators in `base`. Did you intend to?

Comment: You would need something like `base operator+ (const base & other) override { if (auto * other_ = dynamic_cast<der1 *>(&other) { return *this + *other_; } return static_cast<base &>(*this) + other; }`

Comment: Thank you Caleth. Yes, something like that would work, but I would rather not have my operator+ (and many other functions) polluted with if statements for the large number of classes that I want to implement.

Comment: Then why is there an inheritance relationship?

Comment: I think it is preferable that I could add derived classes without having to change the base class. With your implementation I would have to change the ```operator+``` in the base class whenever I add some derived class.
I just want to be able to use the base class independently for different implementations of derived classes, without having to change any code.

Comment: no, that's in the derived class, so that when you do `base * base1 = new der1; auto res = *base1 + *base1` res is a `der1`. At the moment, it isn't

Comment: All in all, I suggest *not* mixing binary operators with inheritance

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you should never use explicit `new`/`delete` and you should follow [`RAII`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

If I understood your issue, I would get rid of `type` and `gettype` and instead use a virtual `clone`:

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<base> clone() const
    {
        return std::make_unique<base>(*this);
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<base> clone() const override
    {
        return std::make_unique<derived>(*this);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment!
This works well for the example I posted above, but it means I have to change everything to work with these ```std::unique_ptr```, instead of references or normal pointers. 
I will try if I can implement this in the full code. It seems like a more reliable solution than what I had.

Comment: I have implemented your solution like this:
```
virtual std::unique_ptr<base> operator+ ( const base & other){
  std::unique_ptr<base> ret = this->clone();
  *ret += other;
  return ret;
 }```
This has no memory leaks, and is somewhat usable. However, I still can't do things like ```x+x+x```. I have to resort to ```(*(x+x))+x)```, which is not so nice. Is this the best that can be done in C++? Or did I not fully understand your solution?

Comment: @user2237652 another route you could go is compile-time polymorphism aka templates. You would get the `x + x * x` syntax but you would lose the possibility to store your objects in a container. With templates you can even do lazy evaluation which you can use to speed up your computations. To give you more concrete advice I would need to better understand your use case, i.e. what exactly are you trying to model.

Comment: In the end I want to make something like an algebra package. The derived types should represent things like interpolated physical entities, such as the temperature-distribution interpolated over an object. I want to be able to simply put in an expression as ```unew = alpha (dx(dx(uold))+dy(dy(uold))+dz(dz(uold)))```, where I have a large flexibility in the way I represent the field ```u```.
However, I plan on making a python frontend anyway, and since python is a bit more flexible, I should probably only try to implement operator+ fully in python and not in C++.

Comment: In the end this means that the most important things are speed and extendability. 
For now I don't care too much about being able to throw exceptions at the right moment. It's completely fine if it crashes compeletely when something is wrong.
I haven't thought about templates too much. I'll look into it.

Comment: Templates seem to be a powerful construction. But since it's compile-time polymorphism, I don't think I can extend this polymorphism into python. Python does everything on run-time without compilation. Therefore, the interface between python and C++ (boost) will never know in advance on what types a certain operation is called and compilation is impossible.
Within C++ templates are very powerful, but I'm a bit afraid what happens when you expend it towards other languages.